# Is there an option to tell crawlers / bots: "don't use javascript"?

Tags: javascript, seo, bots

I was searching for this subject with no results, so I consider asking a question. I know that there is an option to make pages loaded by AJAX "crawable", using www.example.com/#!somecontent. But is there an option (i.e. Meta tag or robots.txt variable) that say: "Hey, robots, disable javascipt!"?

It can be used in example by:

1) online javascript games, which has huge amount of javascript, and nothing special for SEO and bots to crawl (bots memory and time saver)

2) To build a site using PHP, HTML, CSS (with meta tags change, etc) for robots. And then add some extra functionality (in example reload only content, but NOT CHANGE META TAGS) using AJAX, that crawlers and bots don't need to analyze. In that case bots see meta tags, and contents, and You prevent default actions for anchors, and user only reload content via AJAX, and meta tags are standard in that case.

PS) The question isn't about: You can do it better, or You can rebuild application in other way. It is about: can we suggest bots to disable javascript.

Comment: Most crawlers do not crawl javasript.  They load the HTML/XHTML only.

Comment: @Kaml, [Google does](http://mashable.com/2010/06/25/google-javascript/).

Comment: Google does... As I said, Google crawl #! after site url to crawl even AJAX applications...

Comment: Don't think bots would want this.  This would easily be abused and would lead to sites appearing one way for bots and another way for users.  This is the reason google implemented the ability to crawl pages with javascript/ajax in the first place because site owners were hiding spammy content via javascript.

Comment: @Jrod I understand that. And I fully agree. But I was wondering that there is some kind of suggest: "Hello bot! Maybe without javascript..." ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is **no, you can not**.

The long answer is, if you have more than one version of your content, use **[Canonical link element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element)** in one link that use javascript that link to a page that do not have javascript enabled. You can append to url one parameter like `no_js=1` and via server side remove all parts of your HTML that use Javascript.

So, yes, with some work you can do it.